# Does Corsair USB Flash Survivor Stealth use MLC or TLC flash?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

(This also probably pertains to the "non-Stealth" version as it's just a different housing I believe).

I have searched online everywhere I can possibly think of.   I find no datasheet designating if this drive uses MLC or TLC.

Other brands say specifically if it uses a MLC or TLC in the marketing material (to be clear, I'm referring to USB Flash Drives, not SSD where MLC and TLC also comes into play).

Also, many years ago Corsair definitely was proud of designating their drive as SLC or MLC  (SLC being superior).    However, nowadays for a consumer level Flash drive it's going to be either MLC or TLC (with the exception of one or two particular expensive SLC based units).

**One possible clue**:  I'm achieving about **200 MB / sec  Read speeds** in Windows 7 (haven't tested write speed yet).    **I'm not sure if raw speed can help indicate if it's MLC or TLC possibly?**

Comment: TLC is pretty rare at the moment, there's one(?) manufacturer which makes it, and I've only seen them on SSDs

Comment: For USB Flash drives: Transcend JetFlash 790 and many others in this class use TLC, I can say for certain (it's in their marketing materials).   Transcend JetFlash 780 uses MLC though (again, in their marketing materials).  For  SSD: I'm not entirely certain, but I think Samsung might be the only manufacturer that uses TLC in their EVO line.   So, I thought it was pretty rare to find TLC in USB flash drives as well, but  http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2261046  (if accurate) indicates Sandisk uses TLC in some of their USB Flash Drives as well. I guess it's catching on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corsair Flash Survivor Stealth 64GB USB 3.0 uses `Sandisk SDYNQGCRM 032GUL` memory modules ([source](http://www.tweaktown.com/reviews/5381/corsair-flash-survivor-stealth-64gb-usb-3-0-flash-drive-review)):

- Cropped image (full-size on click):

  [image: Cropped image]

There is not much info about these modules on the Internet, but flash support list for [IS903 USB 3.0 single chip UFD controller](http://www.innostor.com/Product_IS903.html) lists them as `MLC` ones:

[image: Flash support list for IS903 USB 3.0 single chip UFD controller]

This document is not available on the Innostor website, but can be googled by it's name (`IS903 NAND Flash Support List`) on various filesharing sites, e.g.: [IS903 NAND Flash Support List_V1.0.4](http://wenku.baidu.com/link?url=c1tg13KECMRaPjbTryX_iP2JOmHtAVuQGAutX_W69-W7R_fL6HUu1GM6rhXWIzKJ1hdU1EJBDrm3ImITeJG9dLhtSUpbS-KRHcqVY-zTnwO)

Moreover, these chips were used in `Transcend MSA740` SSD and its specs tell that it's uses `MLC` memory with `Toggle Mode`:

- B&H: [Transcend 128GB MSA740 SATA III 6 Gbps mSATA Solid State Drive](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/920426-REG/transcend_ts128gmsa740_128gb_msa740_sata_iii.html)
- Newegg: [Transcend 128GB mSATA Solid State Disk SATA III 6Gbps Model TS128GMSA720](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA1K60YU3821)
- Various russian reviews (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for `MLC` and `SDYNQGCRM`): [1](http://www.osp.ru/pcworld/2015/01/13044158/), [2](http://www.overclockers.ru/lab/58448/Testiruem_nakopiteli_mSATA_120A-128_Gbajt_Crucial_M50A0A_Intel_525_Transcend_SSD740A_i_Kingston_mS20A0A.html), [3](http://ru.gecid.com/storag/transcend_ts128gmsa740/), [4](http://www.dgl.ru/reviews/obzor-ssd-nakopiteley-s-interfeysom-msata-ssd-v-miniature_6138.html), [5](https://www.overclockers.ua/storage/transcend-msa740-128gb/)

Unfortunately, [Transcend's press release for this drive](http://www.transcend-info.com/About/press/10062) doesn't mention the memory type.

Comment: Most definitely the answer I was searching for.   Absolutely marking this answer as the solution!   Thank you!    One note:  the yellow highlighted row seems to show  SDYNRGCRM-032GUL  but the  chip graphic above is actually SDYNQGCRM-032GUL    ("R" should be "Q")  (as you indicated correctly in the line "Various russian reviews...").  I was able to find the exact same specs with your link for the "Q" version as well though in the section below the "1ynm"  (essentially same exact info for the row you highlighted).   You really went above and beyond with your research and answer. THANKS AGAIN.

Comment: @mike2000 Yep, I've messed up screenshots, fixed now :).